# Azure website, backup does not work

Tags: azure, backup, azure-web-app-service

Every time trying backup site I get

> Could not start backup for website 'rockietm'. Backup is currently in
>   progress. You cannot schedule another one right now:

[image]

Somebody met this problem? Tried to clear existing backups in 'Storage' settings, no result..

Comment: Created "Recovery service" instance, to see if there is a job I can cancel, but don't see any jobs there: http://oi57.tinypic.com/30wp205.jpg

Comment: This might be caused by the service upgrade of the infrastructure and it will go away in the next 48 hours (timeout for backups). Apologies for the inconvenience. We already prepared a fix for this issue (so service upgrades won't cause such failures + the timeout will be reduced to 24 hours), so it shouldn't happen again in the future. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ Petr Podhorsky aah, ok! thank You for response! :)